# Unrecognized selector sent?

Tags: iphone, xcode, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I've been mucking around with MonoTouch and the Xcode interface builder from some sample code which had an interface defined already.

After adding a button and giving it a click callback I found one of the buttons was no longer responding to clicks and instead crashing out:

> 2011-09-30 01:51:35.361 RedLaserSample[19437:707]
>   -[RLSampleViewController scanPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x17e1260 MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException:
>   Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException
>   Reason: -[RLSampleViewController scanPressed]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x17e1260   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main
>   (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String
>   delegateClassName) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   RedLaserSample.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/dev/Desktop/chrisbranson-RedLaserSample-0311fa6/RedLaserSample/Main.cs:28

Any ideas what could be causing this and how I could fix it?

Comment: Did you intent "scanPressed:" (with a parameter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, for some reason I had to re-add the click event in the Xcode builder.. perhaps the project being built with an older version of mono broke itself when a newer way of adding button callbacks was added in?

Comment: Same issue, same solution. Odd.